# How to not echo here document to terminal?

Tags: bash, ssh, heredoc, stty

I have a script that prompts the user for their sudo password, and then iterates through a list of hosts and performs commands on remote hosts.  I can 'read -s' to get their password silently, but each time their password is used on a remote host, it's echoed back to the terminal.  Changing stty on the local host doesn't help.  Example:

```
#!/bin/sh -x

echo "Enter sudo pass:"
read -s SUDOPASS

stty_orig=$(stty -g)
stty -echo
ssh -tt remote_host sudo cat /etc/cma.conf <<EOP
$SUDOPASS
EOP
stty $stty_orig
```

The output still includes the password:

```
+ ssh -tt remote_host sudo cat /etc/cma.conf
My_P4ssW0rd!
Password:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
```

It also doesn't help to play with stty on the remote host:

```
stty_orig=$(ssh -t remote_host stty -g)
ssh -t remote_host stty -echo
ssh -tt remote_host sudo cat /etc/cma.conf <<EOP
$SUDOPASS
EOP
ssh -t remote_host stty $stty_orig
```

FWIW, I'm mainly concerned with OSX bash/sh

Comment: You should use `IFS= read -rs SUDOPASS` just in case there are some spaces and backslashes in the password.

Answer (score 1):

Try `expect`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Enter sudo pass:"
read -s SUDOPASS

expect -c 'spawn ssh -tt remote_host sudo cat /etc/cma.conf ; expect -re "\\\[sudo\\\] password for .*:"; send "'"$SUDOPASS"'\n";interact'
```

Comment: Err, no... try it yourself.  The '-x' was there for me to follow along.  I can reproduce the issue without enabling debugging.

Comment: Oh sorry... I read it wrong. I thought you are not getting `ssh` password printed on the screen. It's `sudo` password, that's giving you the issue. Updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I haven't spotted the problem here. But I often redirect the output manually to silence it:

```
ssh -tt remote_host sudo cat /etc/cma.conf <<EOP >& /dev/null
```

I'm not sure if this will help.